# SPO PowerShell - How to add AD Group as permission on a Document Library Folder

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am writing a PS script to create a site with a doc library.  The doc library will have many folders, each of which need its permissions set via an AD Group.  I have been using PNP PowerShell, but see no way to do this.  I can assign SharePoint Groups to the folders, but I need to assign Domain Groups (AD groups).  Been searching for hours, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could give it go with something like this:

```
Connect-PNPOnline -Url "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteCollection"
$web = Get-PnPWeb
#replace AzureAD-SecurityGroup-ID with the actual GUID from that group
$group = "c:0t.c|tenant|AzureAD-SecurityGroup-GUID"
$ensureUser = $web.EnsureUser($group)
$user = Get-PnPUser -Identity $group
Add-PnPUserToGroup -LoginName $user.LoginName -Identity "SharePoint Group Name"
```

Comment: Thanks Murilo, 
In the EnsureUser command, do I need to do some substitutions, for instance, if my tenant was "MyTenant" and the AD group was names "My-AD-GROUP", would I use this:

$ensureUser = $web.EnsureUser("c:0t.c|MyTenant|My-AD-GROUP")

And for Add-PnPUserToGroup, does that work for a folder in the Doc Library?  

Thanks!

Comment: Hey Troy, instead of the group name, use the GUID from that group e.g.51fr34gb-byh2-7235-lh51-d5g8s2er1a6f. You can get that from Azure AD. Once you get the $user, see if there's anything on the $user.LoginName. No changes necessary for |tenant|

Comment: So I pulled the guid for the AD group, but when I run the Get-PnPUser command I get:Get-PnPUser : The specified user c:0t.c|tenant|c1dbfc71-4685-4021-ac50-50319ed408f6 could not be found.

Comment: so it appears that $ensureUser = $web.EnsureUser($group) is not returning anything of value

Comment: I am trying to apply the group permission to the folder via: 

Set-PnPListItemPermission -List "Documents" -Identity $folder.Id -Group $ADGroupID -AddRole 'Read'

and I have tried several IDs fro $ADGroupID, the guid, the sid, the distinguished name, nothing works, it just says Group can not be found.

Answer (score 0):

This should be way easier, but I found a solution.

First, you sometimes need to break permission inheritance. You can do this by executing the following:

```
$web = Get-PnPWeb
$web.BreakRoleInheritance($false, $false)
$web.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

After that, you need the ID of the Azure AD group. You can get this by using the AzureAD module for PowerShell. (Get-AzureADGroup)

Then, you can run the following command:

```
Set-PnPWebPermission -User "c:0t.c|tenant|<<your group id>>" -AddRole "<<the desired permission level>>"
```

This also works for other commands, like `Set-PnPListPermission` and `Set-PnPListItemPermission`.

---

TL;DR: simply specify the group ID in the `-User` parameter.